# javascript innerHTML in mozilla

Tags: javascript

When I alert result of `document.formname.elements.length` mozilla does not consider elements which i dynamically added in table using following function.

```
var rowCounter = 1;

  for (i=0; i<oldIndex.length; i++)
    {
      newRow = tableToSort.insertRow((oldIndex.length+rowCounter));
      for (c=0; c<tableToSort.rows[i+1].cells.length; c++)
        {
          newCell = newRow.insertCell(c);
          newCell.innerHTML = tableToSort.rows[oldIndex[i]].cells[c].innerHTML;
          newCell.className="tblfirstcol";

        }
        rowCounter++;
      }
```

What is the problem here ?

Comment: Mozilla (the software) has been dead for half a decade. Do you mean Firefox?

Comment: Assuming your assigning control elements to the new cell that works fine in FF your going to need to expand your test case

Answer (score 0):

Almost all browsers ignore elements pasted to document by `innerHTML`, in the way or an other (loosing ids etc.).

1. You first have to create the elements to the document, and then append them to the `newCell` by `appendChild()` method.
2. If the cell in `oldIndex[i]` is supposed to remove from the page, you can also use `swapNodes()`-method.

I'll test, if the HTML in the cell in `oldIndex[i]` could be copied as whole element. So, I'll be back...

Well, forget all above in this answer. This should be working, place these two lines instead of line where you've put `innerHTML` into `newCell`.

```
var cellContent = tableToSort.rows[oldIndex[i]].cells[c].cloneNode(true);
newCell=newRow.appendChild(cellContent);
```

OOPS! The code adds the whole cell. Corrected. Now leave out the original `newCell` definition too.

Comment: I have first column with checkboxex this code not shows checkboxes and table looks very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that form.elements only refers to elements in the form that take place in the form-submission algorithm. So, if you add another P element to the form, that doesn't increase form.elements.length. If you add an INPUT element though, it would.

With the following, I get 1, then 2, then 3 in the alert, which is expected. The last step inserts an INPUT element with innerHTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                var form = document.forms.test;
                alert(form.elements.length);
                var table = form.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
                alert(form.elements.length);
                var another_row = table.insertRow(-1);
                var another_cell = another_row.insertCell(-1);
                another_cell.innerHTML = "<input>";
                alert(form.elements.length);
            }, false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="test">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```